# Pass custom object to WTForm

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I need to pass an object from my database to my form, from which i want to read the default values out. My current code looks like this:

My initialisation:

```
form = EditEventForm(event)
```

And my form class:

```
class EditEventForm(FlaskForm):
    def __init__(self, event):
        self.event = event

    name = StringField('Name', validators=[DataRequired()],     default=self.event.name)
    description = TextAreaField('Description', validators=[DataRequired()], default=self.event.description)
    street = StringField('Street and number', validators=[DataRequired()], default=self.event.street)
    city = StringField('City', validators=[DataRequired()], default=self.event.city)
    time = StringField('Time', validators=[DataRequired()], default=self.event.time)
```

But obviously, the form cannot access the self-context. Is there another way i can achieve it so my fields can read the data out from a passed object?

Comment: Are you looking for [`FlaskForm(obj=…)`](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=obj%3D)?

Comment: @Kay looks good, but how do i access this from within the form? just obj.attribute?

Comment: A form is not associated with an object, or vice versa. Read out an object with `FlaskForm(obj=…)`, and set the values of an object with [`FlaskForm.populate_obj(…)`](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html#wtforms.form.Form).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your task is just to populate form with default data you can do it like this:

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField, TextAreaField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class EditEventForm(Form):
    name = StringField('Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    description = TextAreaField('Description', validators=[DataRequired()])
    street = StringField('Street and number', validators=[DataRequired()])
    city = StringField('City', validators=[DataRequired()])
    time = StringField('Time', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

And then populate your newly created form with desired data

```
form = EditEventForm()
form.name.data = event.name
form.description.data = event.description
form.street.data = event.street
form.city.data = event.city
form.time.data = event.time
```

**Edit**

As was suggested in the comments the stated above pattern is bad because when either model or form object is changed then all instances of form creation must be tracked down. One can use someting like this instead:

```
# attributes of the event object matching form field names will be used for field values
form = EditEventForm(obj=event)

# populates the attributes of the passed obj with data from the form’s fields
form.populate_obj(event)
```

From the [documentation](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html#wtforms.form.Form):

> Note: This is a destructive operation; Any attribute with the same name as a field will be overridden. Use with caution.

Comment: Oh wasn't aware of that, but yes, obviously, thanks a lot :)

Comment: This is an extremely bad pattern. If either the form or the object class is changed, then all instances of the Form creation need to be tracked down. That makes a project unmaintainable.

Comment: What Kay said - if you have to do somethin like this, do it in the form's `__init__`, not outside.

Answer (score 0):

From [the FineManual](http://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html#wtforms.form.Form.__init__):

> **init**(formdata=None, obj=None, prefix='', data=None, meta=None, **kwargs) 
>   Parameters:
>      (...) 
>      obj – If formdata is empty or not provided, this object is checked for attributes matching form field names, which will be used for field values.

Comment: Does `obj` need to be a dict or what type of data needs it to be? Sometimes I miss explicity in the docs..